# Why does long array initialzation show error in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Compilation Error:

Compilation Error

prog.java:18: error: '.class' expected

```
     long[] array=new long[int];

                              ^
```

prog.java:19: error: '.class' expected

```
     long[] array1=new long[int];

                               ^
```

2 errors

Answer (score 2):

Between the square brackets you're supposed to put the size of the array you want, not a type such as `int`.

Try something like this instead:

```
// Create an array of long with 10 elements
long[] array = new long[10];
```

See [Java Tutorial: Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to learn how to work with arrays.